# How to get Text from UI.InputField?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field, unity3d-gui

I want to retrieve the text from a UI `InputField` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it by first getting reference to the gameObject somehow then getting the `InputField` component from it and taking the component's `text` variable:

```
    GameObject inputFieldGo = GameObject.Find("PathToTheGameObject");
    InputField inputFieldCo = inputFieldGo.GetComponent<InputField>();
    Debug.Log(inputFieldCo.text);
```

Comment: Also dont forget to put `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of the script!

Comment: Awesome I was looking for this as well, thanks @maZZZu!

Comment: What if you have more than 1 input field?

Comment: If you have more than one, you can use `GetComponents` instead of `GetComponent` to get all of them.